# SSL certificates work fine from command line but fails in script

Tags: linux, ssl, configuration, ssl-certificate, openssl

I'm trying to setup email notifications for my continuous integration server.  I have a script which uses nail to send the email when the build works:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Build Worked!" | nail -A myisp -s 'Build Success' my_email@gmail.com
```

When I run this from the command line with `sh build-worked`, it works and I receive the email.  However, when I start the continuous integration server which executes the same script, I get the following error:

```
nail: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8: no version information available (required by nail)
nail: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: no version information available (required by nail)
Error with certificate at depth: 0
 issuer = /C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
 subject = /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=smtp.gmail.com
 err 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
Continue (y/n)? could not initiate SSL/TLS connection: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
. . . message not sent.
```

I must be messing some configuration, any ideas?

Comment: I've never used nail before but I'd use 'su - ' to become the user that the script runs as and then debug from there.  It may be that on the first interactive run it'll ask you to confirm that the ssl certificate is correct and then it'll run ok scripted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems where something runs from the shell but won't from `cron` or `init` or `daemon` or some other environment are usually caused by differences in the environment.

- Use absolute paths to executables and data files
- Explicitly set your `PATH` variable to make sure it includes what you need
- Explicitly set other environment variables that your process needs

Since it looks like `nail` is complaining about some libraries, it's likely that an environment variable points one way in one environment and another (or not at all) in another.

I'm not familiar with BitNami, but on my system those libraries are in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` (and `/lib/i586` and similar).